# Uncoutable Borel Set of Polish Space Contains Cantor Set: Proof Step

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets, cantor-set, polish-spaces

Currently, I am struggling to fully understand the following theorem from Alexander Kechris' book “Classical Descriptive Set Theory”:

> [image: Theorem]

The last sentence is unclear to me. Why is the homeomorphic copy of $\mathcal{C}$ with respect to $\mathcal{T}_A$ also homeomorphic with respect to $\mathcal{T}$?

It has been shown that there is $Y \subseteq A$ s.t. $(Y, \mathcal{T}_A|Y)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$. But why is $(Y, \mathcal{T}|Y)$ also homeomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

A Cantor set is compact, so the identity $(C,\mathcal{T}_A) \to (C,\mathcal{T})$ is a homeomorphism. IT follows that if $(Y, \mathcal{T_A}|Y)$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, then so is $(Y, \mathcal{T}|Y)$.

Comment: Can you please explain how it follows from the Cantor set being compact that the identity $(C,\mathcal{T}_A) \to (C,\mathcal{T})$ is a homeomorphism? My knowledge in topology is rather basic.

Comment: @qwertz continuity follows from the inclusion. Closeness from compactness. Maybe you aren’t ready for Kechris yet?